# iviewer "centers" off-center and "fits" too small within Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I've created a popup using Bootstrap modals, from within Splunk HTML dashboard. The popup works great, but there is some problem with an iviewer within it.

The iviewer somehow thinks its size and position are not what they are. When I "loadImage" there, into the iviewer created with "`zoom: fit`", the image is shifted up and to the left and is definitely smaller than what 'fit' would imply. When I use `iviewer('center')`, it centers around some point similarly shifted up and to the left.

Any CSS attributes to look for? To override in my own CSS (I can do that by ID, thus not affecting anything else)?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: the element to which iviewer is attached has its width and height specified as 100%, which iviewer for some reason takes as 100 - it does not recalculates into pixels (sounds like a bug to me, btw). Once I specified the width and height in pixels, everything started working just fine. It has nothing to do with either Bootstrap or Splunk.